# Non-polymorphically Invoke Instance Method in D?

Tags: polymorphism, invoke, d, instance-methods

How do you statically invoke a particular definition of an instance method from *outside* the class of the object, so as to inhibit polymorphism in that particular use? (In other words: I need the equivalent of Visual Basic.NET's `MyClass`, but from the outside.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the call by building a delegate and calling it. From memory:

```
void delegate(int, float) dg;

dg = &t.theFunction;  // gives the function for the dynamic type
// OR
dg.ptr = t;  // gives the object

dg.funcptr = &typeof(t).theFunction; // gives the function for the static type 

dg(1,3.1415);
```

OTOH this is a hack in my book and for some types will be sure to cause problems.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh so you can use `fnptr` like this... *that's* what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Lambert: BTW, it's spelled `funcptr`: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/function.html#closures My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using polymorphic class methods when that isn't the behavior you desire? I'm also not sure what you mean by outside the class (is it that you want to call a member function without an instance of the object)?

I'll make some assumptions that what you probably should do is write normal functions which take objects as a first parameter.

```
binarySize(MyClass myObject) {  ... }
```

A feature that hasn't yet been added to any D compiler is the ability to call this like so:

```
myObject.binarySize();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm using polymorphic methods because I *sometimes* need them, but sometimes don't -- I need both behaviors for each case. (Oh, and by outside the class, I mean external code.)
By `object` I assume you meant `myObject`, correct? I'm not sure if this'll help, but I'll look into it; thanks.

Comment: @Lambert, I had used object as it was not code from within the binarySize function and thus could be any variable name. I think this will be the best option, if you want polymorphic behavior call the class method, otherwise you should call the non-polymorphic function. Adding methods from outside a class is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `typeof(this).myfunc()` inside class instance function to make non virtual call. If you need to call virtual method non-virtually from outside class, you can add new (final) method to class which will wrap the call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the problem is, I *have* to do this from outside the class, and I can't really add new methods to the class, because I have very generic code that works up and down a hierarchy -- I need to be able to say `object.binarySize()` at every level in the hierarchy for that particular level, and I can't add another function at each level for every class because that's just not practical. (Mixins don't help either.)